# Is there any way to remove markers on python googlemaps api?

Tags: python, google-maps, optimization, plot, gmplot

I'm using the googlemaps and gmplot libs on Python to plot waypoints and directions on a .html map, but can't find a way to remove the A and B markers and leave out only the route. These markers refer to to the starting and ending point of a trajectory on a Google map.

I've found that this is possible in other languages (ie JavaScript) using suppressMarkers under the DirectionsRendererOptions -what seems to be a- function. I've searched everywhere and can't find a way or a similar function on the python lib, tho. This capability, if existent, i think would be either inside the googlemaps lib or the gmplot lib (i guess this one).
If anyone knows anything about that and can help me in some way, i'll be very glad. thanks =)

+Plus: i'm only trying to remove them because i've found a way to plot correctly the optimal route, which didn't seem to be possible plotting the actual " *plotmap.directions(start, end, waypoints=list, optimize_waypoints = True, traffic_model = 'best_guess',departure_time=datetime.now())* " function. It would return the optimized waypoints order correctly but would show all wrong in the map. Problem is, the method I found to plot the routes correctly is doing directions() through a for loop using the optimized order, which leaves me with a map full of A and B markers. Thats why i need to remove them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for **googlemaps**, but **gmplot** currently doesn't have the ability to suppress those markers.

In the meantime, however, you could modify the produced HTML file to suppress them; look for...

```
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map}).setDirections(response);
```

...and set `suppressMarkers` there:

```
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map, suppressMarkers: true}).setDirections(response);
```

(You could also modify your installed copy of the library and update the `DirectionsRenderer`-related code there.)

Comment: Thanks, this information sure will be useful. Would you know any ways of making this modification directly using python, given that the rest of the code is? ie: through python, replace "map: map" with "map: map, suppressMarkers: true" on the map.html file

Comment: @VictorCaldas A hacky way to replace it could be something like: `map_string = gmap.get().replace('DirectionsRenderer({map: map', 'DirectionsRenderer({map: map, suppressMarkers: true')`, then just write `map_string` to an HTML file: `with open("map.html", "w") as f: f.write(map_string)`. (`gmap` would be your `gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter()` object)